# What should one do with extra Japanese Yen, if they're not planning to stay in Japan?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, japan

Consider an individual who:

1. is currently working for a short period of time in Japan (~2 months),
2. will begin working in Europe directly after,
3. and may possibly work in the USA within the next 10 years.

Suppose that the individual has a moderate amount (on the order of hundreds of thousands) of Japanese Yen (JPY) left at the end of their working period in Japan, and they do not expect to travel to Japan within the foreseeable future.

What should this individual do?

For example:

1. Exchange from JPY to USD,
2. exchange from JPY to EUR,
3. spend the rest of the money in Japan,
4. or somehow pay for goods in other countries with JPY?

Comment: Are you saying you have physical cash yen?  It's hard to say how to value #3 against the others, since it depends how much stuff you have that you want/need to spend the money on "anyway" (as opposed to spending it arbitrarily just to get rid of it).

Answer (score 2):

A few thousand bucks? I'd swap to the currency of whatever country you're going to next.